# problem with recursion and string equal function

Tags: java, recursion, equals

'   the code is suppose to look for target in substrings of str. It compares subtstrings of str to target. it starts comparing from the first substring (that is made of characters from 0 index upto target.length-1 index for str). if substring is not equal to target it removes the first character from str and returns it to the function again. if str length is less than target length, it returns false. '

'example, if str = "superman" & target = "man". The first substring is "sup" compared with target "man". This is false, so "s" gets removed. next substring is "upe" compared with "man", again false, so "u" gets removed. next "per" with "man" and "p" gets removed.'

'Until the substring is "man" compared with target "man". Here, it should return true, but it doesnt and instead proceeds to removing "m" and continuing'

'most probably the problem is in line 7'

```
public static boolean contains(String str, String target) {
    if(str == null || target == null) {   //null check
        return false;
    }
    if(str.length() < target.length()) {  // when string has less size than target, naturally its false
        return false;
    } else if(target.equals(str.substring(0,target.length()-1))) {  //this is where the problem is
                                                                    //more specifically, it isn't comparing the strings. 
                                                                    //Here if str and target are equal they should return true, but when the target is equal to str, it doesnt return true, instead treats it is if target is not equal to str.
        return true;
    } else {
        return contains(str.substring(1),target);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not simply using str.contains(target)? This is already available in the standard java lib

Comment: `target.length()-1` is wrong. Read the documentation for [String.substring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,int%29) again. Or print out the result of `str.substring(...)`

Comment: Every good programmer knows how to debug his code. Assuming you haven't already read it, perhaps this will help: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @davidgiga1993 the whole point was to make my own function(class project).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn yeah it worked when I removed -1, thanks. havent used string functions that much.

Comment: @Abra debugged it and was able to identify that the problem was on line 7. but couldnt figure out what the problem was, hence i posted it here. Now fixed, was using substring function wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the problem is in line 7, you don't have to substract 1 to target.

Method:

```
public static boolean mycontains(String str, String target) {
    if(str == null || target == null) {   
        return false;
    }
    if(str.length() < target.length()) {  
        return false;
    } else if(target.equals(str.substring(0,target.length()))) {  
        return true;
    } else {
        return mycontains(str.substring(1),target);
    }
}
```